# jQuery Cycle Plugin Position Issue in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, position, cycle

The issue is occurring under the 'Account Services Team' section on [this page](http://www.nba.com/warriors/season-ticket-holders-sth-page-test).

Internet Explorer 9 seems to be fine, but if you turn on [Compatibility View](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/How-to-use-Compatibility-View-in-Internet-Explorer-9) you'll notice that the images fading in and out via the [Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) are now in middle of the containing div rather than in their proper place on the left.

I have tried positioning the containing div as a floating element, an inline-block element, and now as absolutely positioned, but the same issue keeps occurring regardless.

Here is the code block in question (note that I will remove the unsightly inline styling once I find a proper fix):

```
    <div id="accountservicereps_sth">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 14px; width: 150px; height: 150px;">
            <div class="slideshow_accountservicesteam">
                <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/images/sth_accountservices_brandonschneider_150.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/images/sth_accountservices_jeffbarnet_150.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/images/sth_accountservices_donmoffett_150.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/images/sth_accountservices_joelkretzinger_150.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/images/sth_accountservices_melissaviceral_150.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/images/sth_accountservices_daniellehallam_150.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/images/sth_accountservices_staceybaca_150.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/images/sth_accountservices_tenleyblock_150.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/images/sth_accountservices_tamarastanten_150.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" border="0" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; left: 175px; top: 60px; width: 120px; height: 150px; vertical-align: middle;">
            <a href="http://www.nba.com/warriors/seasonticketholders/accountservicesteam">Meet Your<br />Account Service<br />Representatives!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the anchor tags inside of **slideshow_accountservicesteam** are being positioned absolutely as well. Try adding left:0 to them in the CSS.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! For future reference, the CSS for those anchor tags is actually controlled by the plugin, so I added in 'left: 0' in that js file.